# mysql 2 join error on multiple WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to call specific information from my SQL table using the following statement

```
SELECT `PROP_STREET`, `PROP_PRICE`, `PROP_STATUS`, `AGT_FNAME`, `AGT_LNAME`
FROM `property`, `agent`
WHERE property.PROP_AGENT = agent.AGT_FNAME && property.PROP_STATUS = ("SOLD" , "Available for sale", "Under Contract");
```

As you can see, I am trying to call everything that is listed as `SOLD`, `Available for sale` and `Under Contract`. While I try to do this, I am getting an error `operand should contain 1 coulmn` this only happens when I am trying to call more than 1 `PROP_STATUS`

Answer (score 2):

This is proper syntax for what you're trying to do:

```
select prop_street, prop_price, prop_status, agt_fname, agt_lname
  from property p
  join agent a
    on p.prop_agent = a.agt_fname
 where p.prop_status in ('SOLD', 'Available for sale', 'Under Contract')
```

Some notes:

1. Join conditions belong in the JOIN clause, not the WHERE clause. Although there is no functional difference, it is good practice.
2. && does mean "AND" in other languages, but not SQL. Have to use "and"
3. Use single quotes for literals ('), not double quotes (")
4. Use IN, not =, when specifying more than one literal.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using old JOIN syntax(where clause) and use the newer join (with ON Clause).

```
SELECT `PROP_STREET`, `PROP_PRICE`, `PROP_STATUS`, `AGT_FNAME`, `AGT_LNAME`
FROM `property` INNER JOIN  `agent`
ON property.PROP_AGENT = agent.AGT_FNAME
WHERE  property.PROP_STATUS IN ('SOLD' , 'Available for sale', 'Under Contract');
```